# Microsoft replacement for aspNetEmail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm looking at rewriting an old asp.net site I inherited. It uses aspNetEmail for sending emails, requiring only the mail server for connecting to our exchange server.

I'd like to remove as much reliance on external libraries as possible so was wondering if Microsoft have made a .net equivalent which is as easy to configure/use?

I've looked at EWS API etc but they all require either user authentication or hardcoded username/password for connecting to Exchange, and it also seems to send from an existing account whereas currently with aspNetEmail (and what I'd like to continue doing) is sending from a generic (possibly non existing) address but from the correct/valid domain (and possibly adding a valid reply-to address).

Have I missed something obvious? Should I just stick with aspNetEmail?

Comment: What features of aspNetEmail are you using that aren't part of [System.Net.Mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/)?

Comment: System.Net.Mail looks to have all the functionality required but requires username/password in plaintext of webconfig. Does defaultCredentials="true" allow me to remove the username/password values completely?

Comment: If you didn't have to send credentials with aspNetEmail, then you won't with System.Net.Mail either.

Comment: That's what I assumed but wasn't sure whether there was some hidden config done when previous dev installed/set up the library.

Comment: @KrustyGString: I typically point ASP.NET at the pickup directory for the local IIS SMTP service, and have the credentials configured in the forwarding options of the service. That way, the code and the config file never need to see them.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll knock together some tests but reckon it'll be fine, was nice to get confirmation first as I always had pre-written smtp libraries to use in last job hence the noobie questions. If I do need to hide password I'll prob use similar setup to yours @Richard. If you want to put something as an answer and I can mark it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in [`System.Net.Mail` namespace](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) has enough features for most scenarios.

If you want to avoid storing the credentials in the configuration file, it's fairly easy to point it at the pickup directory for the local IIS SMTP service, and configure the service to deliver messages to your Exchange server with the appropriate authentication.

Alternatively, you could configure the SMTP settings at the server level, and the credentials would be stored in the `applicationHost.config` file in the system directory.

[This article](http://intellitect.com/configuring-windows-smtp-server-on-windows-2008-for-relay/) has a decent walkthrough of the options.